# Compiling an X window system on an Initial RAM filesystem?

Tags: linux, user-interface, window, live, xserver

I have a few questions that I'm really struggling for answers with.

I'm trying to build my own Linux live distribution (from scratch), the catch is i'm really trying to limit the file size as it will run entirely from RAM.

I've managed to get most packages and resources up and running and now i'm experimenting with the GUI side of things.

Firstly, can anyone tell me how large a minimal Xorg is when compiled? I've compiled the source and it has added 200mb+ to the file system size. Have i done something wrong to make it that huge?

Secondly, I've Googled and found Kdrive/Tiny X. If I used the KDrive or TinyX as my Xserver, would I still be able to use applications such as Google Chrome at a later date? Or do such applications require the X window system?

Thanks for your help in advance everyone! Any help will be very much appreciated!

Tom

Comment: What exactly did you compile? Only the Xorg server? Did you also get Xephyr, Xvfb, Xdmx and friends? Did you compile all the xf86 video and input drivers? Libraries? Protocol headers? Xorg apps? What are the compilation parameters for each piece, especially the X server? Do your compilations generate documentation?

Comment: Hi there, apologies for such a late reply. I'm following the Development guide for Xorg, so I probably downloaded the lot. http://www.x.org/wiki/ModularDevelopersGuide#Selecting_a_Build_Process. I was under the impression that it was all needed =S. Thanks